# Does anyone know of a method to do a partial restore of many time machine incremental backups

Tags: macbook, restore, time-machine

I'm trying to extract just the pictures from every backup, there are about 40.   The Macbook Pro that they were backed up from has a failed H/Drive & I'm having to try & copy them to another Macbook with only limited space available.  Most of the other folders have already been copied to Google drive AND did not require multiple copies to get all the content.  However for some strange reason some of the picture folders in the backups are empty & as they are locked until a copy command issued from a user profile specially setup to emulate the old original on the other Mac. In addition as their are only 2 USB ports on this M/C & I need 1 for my mouse, it would be preferable to be able to restore sirect to Google Drive in case the space required exceeds that available on this machines H/Drive.

Comment: I can't quite figure out exactly what you are trying to do. Everything should be in the "Latest" folder, as hard-links to the original sources. Set the disk to 'ignore ownership' & that's the source for your single copy action.

Comment: @ Tetsujin "Thank you a 1,000 times!!" I actioned our comment by moving the folder onto Google drive & "Hay Presto" 5.85 GB of precious historical pictures/videos is now becoming available.  Not sure how to set the disk to "ignore ownership" but if you are to busy no need to explain further as I have another method which achieves this

Comment: Select the disk, right click & 'Get Info'. Ignore ownership should be in the resulting window, checkbox near the bottom.

Comment: @ Tetsujin  Unfortunately my previous method did not work today & I cannot locate the "ignore ownership" option in the resulting window either, as per your latest instruction!  My present Macos is:- "Yosemite" version 10.10.5.  In the resulting window there is an option which allows 1 to change the sharing  options, but I've already got Read & write permisison set & the other options are more restricitive.

Comment: You ought to be able to access that control on any non-boot volume; unlock using your admin credentials then the box is checkable - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIJqA.png

Comment: @ Tetsujin  Thank you for all your comments.  I have now finally noticed that the name of the user profile that has read write permission is NOT mine but my wife's.  Almost certainly if I login to her profile then the folder will be unlocked or become so after I copy it to another location.